# Bootstrap validation with jqBootstrapValidation on dynamically loaded form

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to validate an Ajax loaded form with [jqBootstrapValidation](http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/):

```
var loadUrl = "templates/plugins/account/account.ajax.php";
$("#account").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl, function() {
    $("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation({sniffHtml: false});
});
```

It is not showing the jqBootstrapvalidation messages in a help block as explained. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

Apparantly it is necessary to disable html5 validation in the form itself.

```
<form name="formname" novalidate>
</form>
```

Then it works.